# Can't override GetHashCode (cannot change return type when overriding method int UnityEngine.Object.GetHashCode")

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overriding, gethashcode

I'm using C# in Unity3D game engine. in my MonoBehaviour script I need to override `GetHashCode`. But whenever I do, I get the error `cannot change return type when overriding method int UnityEngine.Object.GetHashCode"` (Isn't GetHashCode located inside the System namespace?)

My overriding:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return index.GetHashCode();
}
```

The error no longer exists if I remove the `using UnityEngine;` header from the top. I tried to explicitly tell it what to override, it's not like dealing with interfaces, so it didn't work.

What's going on here, are there two `GetHashCode`s? how can I override `GetHashCode` here?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have removed the `using System;` and left out `UnityEngine`, same result.

EDIT: I also tried an empty class, and another project, nothing :(

Comment: What does your full class look like?  There is no reason this shouldn't work.  I have several of these functions in Unity 4.2.0f4, all compile fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/516440/cant-override-gethashcode.html#answer-517395). Sorry for the confusion guys, it was a Resharper false error. There was nothing wrong with my code. Thanks for anybody who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

UnityEngine.Object has its own GetHashCode() and to overwrite it you simply do what you've done above, except the return type you have there is wrong. See below:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference? mine and your return types are both ints (index is a struct, which also overrides GetHashCode to return int.GetHashCode) - And to kill all suspicious, I tried return 1; or any int, it still gave the error.

Comment: OK, I tried an empty class, same result :)
using UnityEngine;

public class Entry : MonoBehaviour
{
 public override int GetHashCode()
 {
  return base.GetHashCode();
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

.Net can't understand which Object you are using.

```
using Object=System.Object;
```

try this

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Tried both using Object=System.Object; and using Object=UnityEngine.Object;